# TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY - Touch is not working anymore

Tags: android, overlay

Does anybody have an idea - When I use an application like Twilight (which uses `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`) I can't control my application anymore. Nothing works. Not even the navigation drawer. No touch comes through.

I can't find any solution to this problem. Does anybody have an idea what might be a problem in combination with Screen Overlays?

I have a `DrawerLayout` and a `RelativeLayout` - On both it is not working. So this seems to be no layout issue.

Answer (score 0):

The view used:

```
android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = True
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:filterTouchesWhenObscured).

Answer (score 0):

When you use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY then just add this additional flag:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
```